# Facing crash in Samsung galaxy note 7

Tags: android, sqlite, galaxy

Facing crash on Galaxy note 7:

> Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 2062): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode   #################################################################
>   Error Code :   2062 (SQLITE_CANTOPEN_EMFILE) Caused By : Application has opened two many files.   Maximum of available file descriptors in one process is 1024 in default. (unable to open database file (code 2062): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode)   #################################################################

Comment: You are lucky it's a crash and not an explosion

Comment: Don't use this phone anymore. Go get the 100$ credit back.

Answer (score 0):

You have opened too many files.

Your code forgets to close all its database objects, or other files.

Comment: Cab you please guide? what actually we should do?

Comment: I closed the DB at every method I created. I hope it will work. But its only causing problem with samsung note 7. and I don't have that phone to test    :(.